# How to prevent message from disappearing in a message subfile?

Tags: message, ibm-midrange

I have a RPG program A and a CL program B. A accepts some user input from display file and use it as the entry parameter of B. b processes the entry parameter, and if there is an error the message will be received and resent by B so that it will be displayed on the bottom of the display file using message subfile. This message displaying mechanism works but not completely, as the message sent could only be glanced in a very short period of time, then it disappeared from the display file. What would be the cause of this problem? How to stop the message from disappearing?

Here is the sample code inside program B:

```
DCLF FILE(ECSWIFP1)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF0000) EXEC(GOTO CMDLBL(ERROR))

OVRDBF FILE(ECSWIFP1) TOFILE(ECSWIFP1) SHARE(*YES)
OPNQRYF FILE(ECSWIFP1) QRYSLT(&QRYSTR)
RCVF 
CLOF FILE(ECSWIFP1)
DLTOVR FILE(ECSWIFP1)

RTVDTAARA DTAARA(&E4LIBN/&E4OBJN) RTNVAR(&DTARVAL)
GOTO CMDLBL(END)

ERROR:
CLOF FILE(ECSWIFP1)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF4520)
DLTOVR FILE(ECSWIFP1)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF9841)

MSG:
RCVMSG MSGTYPE(*ANY) MSGDTA(&MSGDTA) MSGID(&MSGID)
IF COMD(%SST(&MSGID 1 3)) *NE 'CPF') THEN(GOTO CMDLBL(MSG))
SNDPGMMSG MSGID(&MSGID) MSGF(QCPFMSG) MSGDTA(&MSGDTA) MSGTYPE(*STATUS) TOPGMQ(*EXT)

END:
ENDPGM
```

And here is part of the display file DDS for displaying message:

```
 A          R MSG                       SFL
 A                                      SFLMSGRCD(24)
 A            S0MSGK                    SFLMSGKEY
 A            S0PGMQ                    SFLPGMQ
 A          R MSGCTL                    SFLCTL(MSG)
 A                                      OVERLAY
 A                                      SFLDSP
 A                                      SFLINZ
 A                                      SFLSIZ(0005)
 A                                      SFLPAG(0001)
 A            S0PGMQ                    SFLPGMQ
```

Suppose there is no matching record based on the query string, then RCVF causes CPF0864 to be sent out, and this message can be displayed on the screen without problem.

But if a record is found and the field values are used in the RTVDTAARA command, and the failure of this command (e.g. data area not found) will causes the problem I described above, which is that the received message can only be glimpsed in a short period of time and then disappears. Why this happens?

Comment: Please post the code for the display file.

Answer (score 1):

The typical sequence is

```
write msgctl
write bottom
exfmt main
```

Make sure that any record format displayed after the message subfile has OVERLAY specified.  Without OVERLAY, 'bottom' will erase the message subfile and 'main' will erase 'bottom'.

[Application Display Programming](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/rzakc/sc415715.pdf) is an old but useful reference.

EDIT After seeing the CL and DDS.

I believe the issue is due to `SNDPGMMSG MSGTYPE(*STATUS)`.  Status messages are special, and do not normally go into a subfile message queue.  The [Messages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rbam6/wmsgs.htm) section in the Infocenter has more information on the different message types.

In CL PGMB, change the SNDPGMMSG to `MSGTYPE(*DIAG) TOPGMQ(*PRV)`.  This will throw the exception message to the caller (to PGMA) as a diagnostic message.  Double check that you have OVERLAY in the DDS where you need it - my example above that would be bottom and main.

Comment: I have made a few more test over the program, and the problem is more complicated than I thought. I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Display file DDS posted. Please check.

Answer (score -1):

This sequence worked and display the message of message-subfile on the screen

The typical sequence is

```
write msgctl
write bottom
exfmt main
```

Make sure that any record format displayed after the message subfile has OVERLAY specified. Without OVERLAY, 'bottom' will erase the message subfile and 'main' will erase 'bottom'. 
c